# GUI.Label затемнение при отрисовке изображений

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой - Unity сам затемняет все отрисовываемые спрайты/картинки (рисую через GUI)
[image: Скрин в отладчике]

На скрине отчётливо видно - мою картинку зелёного яблока (справа в редакторе), юнити рисует очень тёмным, не смотря на то что она достаточно светлая. Так происходит со всеми картинками. Никаких настроек в GUIStyle, относящихся к способу рисования картинки не нашёл. Так же, не помогает **GUI.Color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,1f)** - то есть, даже если я говорю ему чтобы рисовал "без изменений", затемнение остаётся :(

Написал окошки для редактора, рендер в них абсолютно идентичен - то же непонятное затемнение:
[image: Скрин окон редактирования]

Думал, может эта проблема связана с настройками освещения - но ни одни настройки освещения ничего не меняют.

Вот листинг моего сервиса отрисовки для ячейки:

public

```
 class ItemDrawService {

    private GUIStyle labelStyle = null;

        public ItemDrawService(GUIStyle labelStyle){
            this.labelStyle=labelStyle;
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отрисовка предмета в инвентаре
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Рисуемый предмет</param>
    /// <param name="offsetX">Смещение (позиция) инвентаря по x</param>
    /// <param name="offsetY">Смещение (позиция) инвентаря по y</param>
    /// <param name="fixWebPosition">при fixWebPosition=true предмет рисуется "в сетке"</param>
    /// <param name="drawIcon">при drawIcon=false, предмет рисуется без иконки</param>
    public void DrawItem(ItemSlot item, float offsetX, float offsetY, bool fixWebPosition = true, bool drawIcon = true){

        Rect cellRectangle;

        if (fixWebPosition) {

            cellRectangle = new Rect(offsetX + CellSettings.cellPaddingX + (item.position.X - 1) * CellSettings.cellWidth,
                                     offsetY + CellSettings.cellPaddingY + (item.position.Y - 1) * CellSettings.cellHeight,
                                     CellSettings.cellWidth,
                                     CellSettings.cellHeight);

        } else {

            cellRectangle = new Rect(offsetX,
                                     offsetY,
                                     CellSettings.cellWidth,
                                     CellSettings.cellHeight);

        }

        if (drawIcon)
            labelStyle.normal.background = item.item.resource.icon;

        string description = item.item.getCount()>1? item.item.getCount().ToString()+CLang.getInstance().get(Dictionary.K_COUNT) : "";

        GUI.color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,1f);
        GUI.Label(cellRectangle, description, labelStyle);

    }


}
```

Чем можно вывести картинку в юнити "Как есть", без каких либо фильтров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было просто, изменить Color Space на Gamma в настройках:
Edit/Project settings/Player/

[image: screen]

Если же вам требуется оставить настройки Linear, есть ещё 2 решения (взято из [документации](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/LinearLighting.html))

> **GUI и линейные текстуры**
>
> При отрисовке Unity GUI, мы не производим рендеринг в линейном
>   пространстве. Это значит, что у GUI текстур при чтении не должна
>   удаляться гамма-коррекция. Этого можно достичь двумя путями:
>
> - Указать тип текстуры GUI в настройках импорта текстуры
> - Отметить флажок ‘Bypass sRGB Sampling’ в расширенном режиме импорта текстуры (Texture Type надо установить в Advanced)